# excel export table name with space but in excel get the sheet name with "_" C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

I using C# to write code that exporting table to excel in ".xls" format, and try to give the sheet name name with space.

I try something like this:

```
string header = "CREATE TABLE [Table Name]"

string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @FilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";                    

myConnection = new OleDbConnection(constring);
myConnection.Open();

var cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = header;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When running the code its ok and i able to export my excel file with the data,
but the sheet name came with "_" where the space is supposed to be.
"Table_Name"

[image: TableName]

Someone know why it's happening?

Comment: Which C# library are you using to export data in excel?

Comment: OleDbConnection

Comment: Share some code logic to get some clarity.

Comment: hope this will be helpful https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27327904/C-export-to-excel-rename-Excel-sheets-tabs.html

Comment: @a_programmer i edit the code in my Question

Comment: @Dhiren i didn't quite catch that, what i saw is that use Trim is can help me but i need the space in the name....

Comment: @NivKahlon ok let me try in my machine.

Comment: @Dhiren hi, i start to think that OleDb is the criminal here, and he's the one that add the "_". it's possible?

Comment: @NivKahlon, yeah that could be but I need to work around with my own.